# How would I properly write this query in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

both `team_signup` and `signedup` have foreign keys from `comp_name`. I'm trying to list them all in one list so that I have the list of individuals that signed up as well as the teams. I'm thinking maybe some kind of join?

View:

```
session = request.session._session_key    
cart = comp_name.objects.filter(Q team_signup__sessionid = session | Q signedup__sessionid = session)
```

template:

```
{{cart}}
```

models:

```
#for individual sign ups

class signedup(models.Model):
    comp_name = models.ForeignKey(comp_name)
    sessionid = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length = 7, blank=True)


    #dancer information
    dancer_1_fname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    dancer_1_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    dancer_1_email = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

#for team sign ups
class team_signup(models.Model):
    comp_name = models.ForeignKey(comp_name)
    sessionid = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length = 7, blank=True)

    #dancer information
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    team_count = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    team_email = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

I'm probably not using the `Q` right but I don't quite get it, thanks

Comment: I'm confused, to be honest. Could you paste whole models, not just the fields?

Comment: sorry I thought I did, i was able to get a combined list using the Q method, however I cant pull out the exact fields I need ex. dancer_1_fname or team_name.

Comment: Why does it have to be one list? Can't you just have a single list of teams that signed up and a separate list of individuals? BTW, there is a STRONG convention to give classes/models names that are nouns and that always start with uppercase.

Comment: Having the two different list was what i did, however when it came time to submit a cart to paypal, i used forloop counter to keep track of each submission. Since they aren't in the same queryset, I get two different for loops with two duplicate numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chain from itertools,

so first

```
from itertools import chain in the top of your views
```

Then create the queries that you want to combine

finally, call

```
somename = list(chain(query1, query2))
```

Then in you template, just treat it like you would any other queryset

Answer (score 0):

Use backward relationship:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Then You can call Your related fields like

```
comp = comp_name.objects.get(id=1)
comp.signedup_set.all() 
comp.team_signup_set.all()
```